# How to cast a wchar_t to a BYTE* in C

Tags: c, character-encoding, byte, bytebuffer

I want to cast a `wchar_t` variable to a `BYTE *` before sending it through a stream.

I Have

```
wchar_t val[] = L"abc";
```

and I try to cast using:

```
BYTE * bytes = (BYTE *)val;
```

I don't have all the characters when I read bytes; I only have the first character - `"a"`

I think, I do not convert well `wchar_t`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :

```
static void DASH_process_receive(rdpSvcPlugin* plugin, wStream* data_in)
    int bytes;
    wStream* data_out;
    DASHPlugin* DASH = (DASHPlugin*) plugin;

    fprintf(stderr, "DASH_process_receive:\n");

    if (!DASH)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "DASH_process_receive: DASH is nil\n");
        return;
    }

    /* process data in (from server) here */
    /* here we just send the same data back */

    bytes = Stream_Capacity(data_in);
    fprintf(stderr, "DASH_process_receive: got bytes %d\n", bytes);


       wchar_t val[] = L"abc";
       bytes = Stream_Capacity(data_in);

    if (bytes > 0)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "size wcslen val  %zd\n", wcslen(val));

        fprintf(stderr, "size of val  %zd\n", sizeof(val)); //I Have 16

        data_out = Stream_New((BYTE*)val, sizeof(val));


        Stream_Copy(data_out, data_out,sizeof(val));

        /* svc_plugin_send takes ownership of data_out, that is why
           we do not free it */

        bytes = Stream_GetPosition(data_out);
        fprintf(stderr, "DASH_process_receive: sending bytes %d\n", bytes);

        svc_plugin_send(plugin, data_out);
}

    Stream_Free(data_in, TRUE);
}
```

EDIT : Reading data

```
WTSVirtualChannelRead(VirtChannelParamsStart, 20000, (PCHAR)Message, sizeof(Message), &ulBytesRead))

unsigned short Message[1024];
CString paramsPourStarter;
paramsPourStarter = Message;
SetDlgItemText(IDC_ED_DASH_RESU,paramsPourStarter);
```

Answer (score 6):

How are you reading the length of `bytes`?

If `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` (and assuming you're running on a little endian host) the data pointed to by `byte` will look like

```
{'a', '\0', 'b', '\0', 'c', '\0', '\0', '\0'}
```

so `strlen` would stop counting it's length after encountering the null character immediately after `'a'`

When you convert the `wchar_t` array you should also calculate its length using `wcslen`

```
BYTE * bytes = (BYTE *)val;
size_t len = wcslen(val) * sizeof(val[0]);
// pass len to any functions which are passed bytes
```

Comment: simonic thanks for your answer, I already get the length of bytes with  wcslen(val); but I have the same result and when I log sizeof(wchar_t) I have 16 not 2 and when I log wcslen(wchar_t) I have 3 instead of 8? why?

Comment: @Pis I would be surprised if `sizeof (wchar_t)` was 16. `sizeof val` is probably 16 (`sizeof (wchar_t) == 4`, and `val` contains 4 elements). The first three elements of `val` or nonzero, so `wcslen(val) == 3`. But the nonzero `wchar_t`s still contain _0-bytes_, and thus the ordinary string handling functions think it stops after the first byte of the first `wchar_t`.

Comment: @Pis There was a mistake in my suggested calculation of `len`.  See if the updated code works better for you.

Comment: @simonc what is `L` means in `val[] = L"abc";` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It specifies a string literal of unicode (utf16) chars.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx) for details.

Comment: so if I realy understand the problem isn't the cast but the size of my buffer right?

Comment: @simonc yes even I use the updated code I have the same result

Comment: Can you post a full example that demonstrates this problem?  Either updating the code in this question or posting a new question would be fine.  (Posting a new question might get you a wider audience though - you might find that only I notice any updates to this question.)

Comment: @Pis David Heffrnan has disproved what I said about no-one noticing edits to an old question :-).  His answer, that the receiver of your message is treating it as `char*` sounds right.  If you look at the in-memory representation of `val` in my answer, you'll see why this happens.

Answer (score 4):

The casting is fine, and I'm going to assume that you send the correct number of bytes. Which can be found with `sizeof(val)` and equals 8 for the code in your question, assuming that `wchar_t` is a 2 byte UTF-16 character. Or if your `wchar_t` is a 4 byte UTF-32 character then `sizeof(val)` will be 16.

The problem would then be at the other end, in the code that reads the data. I can imagine three obvious failure modes:

1. You fail to read the entire buffer. Perhaps you assume that the content is null terminated and read up to the first zero byte. That would be incorrect since a null `wchar_t` is actually two zero bytes.
2. You read the entire buffer correctly, but you interpret the data as `char*` rather than `wchar_t*`.
3. You read the data correctly and interpret it correctly as `wchar_t*`. But `wchar_t` is UTF-32 on the sender and UTF-16 for the receiver. Which means that you'd interpret the data as UTF-16 when it is in fact UTF-32.

Any of those explanations would explain why you only received the first character.

In any case I think you are going about the problem in the wrong way. You should probably not be passing UTF-16/UTF-32 down the wire. You'd be much better off with a byte oriented encoding for your text and the natural choice is UTF-8.

**Update**

Your update makes it a little clearer what is going on. You are sending UTF-32 data over the wire, but then interpreting that data as UTF-16 (assuming your Windows program is a Unicode program). This mis-match leads to the data being interpreted incorrectly and explains why you only receive the first character. That's item 3 above.

In order to solve this you need to be very clear about how your text is to be encoded. The fundamental problem you have can be observed by the fact that not anywhere in your question do you talk about text encoding. If you want to pass data between different programs you need to agree on a common text encoding. Again, I recommend that you put UTF-8 encoded text on the wire.

You also have a problem that you are assuming that the text is null-terminated. If you have a transmission error then your receiving program has a buffer overrun. The other issue you will need to get on top of is that of endianness. You need all parties to agree a common endianness for the data on the wire. Use network byte order.

Comment: I don't know. It depends on your compiler. On Windows it would be 8, on many *nix platforms would be 16. You still want UTF8.

Comment: My compiler is XCODE on Mac OS

Comment: Your question describes a failure to read the data at the other end. You did not show how you are reading the data, hence my non-specific answer. I can't say more unless you show how you read the data.

Comment: You did not show anywhere near enough. We need to see types, and how you display the string.

Comment: OK, it's clear what is happening now. I've updated my answer.